# How to represent daily work done effectively in daily call with reporting manager sitting abroad

Tags: management, meetings, manager, presentations

In the project I am working each of us need to give daily status to Reporting Manager for the daily development task we had done in a telephonic call as my reporting manager works from US office. I am good in programming and also work hard daily but it seems my reporting manager is not happy with my performance as he ask me to speed up the things and not to other team members even they don't work hard as much as I am and many times take help from me. I want to handle this situation and want to know basics of representing daily work done effectively in such a way that reporting manager get feeling of I am doing lot of work and will get happy with my performance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(about me: i manage remote development teams)

First off, you are doing a great job, and the fact that you took the effort to ask this question in a constructive manner shows that you are staying focused on doing the right things. Keep it up!

The situation you describe is very common and many of us face this challenge. This typically stems from a lack of trust between the manager and the staff member (mostly due to past experiences), and can be resolved by creating a more structured and consistent communication channel.

My recommendation is to focus on the following:

**Clarify expectations:** Try to get the expectation for each task agreed to in an email. For example, if you've been asked to create a new webpage, write out your understanding of the task and its goal in an email, and send back to your manager. The email you send to the manager should be drafted as "This is my understanding, please provide inputs if any of this is different from your expectation."

**Share your approach:**
Write out your approach for completing the task at hand. For the webpage example, this will include details like creating a design, gathering visual assets, collect content, create html structure, add javascript functionality, test on local machine, compile and send to test server, deploy to production, etc.

In this, also mark (with an asterisk, or in brackets) the actions that have a dependency on someone else to complete and give to you. For example, you might have to wait for the designer to create and give you the logo, so clearly call that out.

**Make a plan:**
Create a plan that shows how much time will be required for each task, and what the expected start and end times are. Be as realistic as you can, as this is the commitment you're making to the manager, and the closer you are to your plan, the more credibility you will gain.

Some of your tasks might be related to research, or might be new, making it difficult for you to gauge how much time it'll take. Don't let it hold you back - put your best guess. You can convey that as a target timeline, and as soon as you find out that you'll need more time than planned, inform the manager. Don't wait until the next call.

Depending on how often you have these calls with the offshore manager, you should break down your tasks to have milestones for each call. e.g. if you have a daily call, then your tasks should be listed to what you expect to complete on a daily basis. If you have a weekly call, then list tasks that can be done in 2-3 day chunks.

**Status Updates:**
Send your updates in an email prior to the call, and stick to the same format and structure of committed tasks. This way, you can show the progress you're making, and specifically discuss the challenges you faced in the work that is being done. If a task took longer than expected to complete, then you should explain why it took longer, what you learned and whether or not you need additional help.

**Don't compare to others:**
This is just going to make you dissatisfied. You are working hard, and stay focused on doing so. You need to build your relationship with the manager in an absolute manner, not relative to others.

**Setup time for one-on-one discussion:**
Setup a regular time for you to talk to your manager (on phone, or video), and ask that this time be about you improving your relationship and work output, and not about a status update. Go for these meetings prepared with what you've learned recently, what challenges you faced and how you resolved them, what other coworkers you helped out, and also what other things you'd like to learn or get better at. This will give your manager better insight into how you perform and will start to trust you more.

**Stay consistent:**
None of this will work if you do parts of these actions at random. It will take time, and a lot of effort and discipline. But if you make a consistent habit out of your communication model, you will see your relationship improving, and your own productivity going up.

I wish you all the best!